# c++ Printing from a struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm working on something and the gist of what I have to do is essentially:

1) Declare a struct named partType that has two members: name (holds the name of a
part) and code (holds a whole number).

2) Declare two variables of type partType.

3) Prompt the user to enter the name and code of the first item and store them
into the corresponding variable.

4) Prompt the user to enter the name and code of the second item and store them
into the corresponding variable.

5) Compare the items by code and display an output like the one shown in the
examples below:

Example 1:
Enter name and code of item1: bolt 22222

Enter name and code of item2: nut 11111

bolt goes after nut in the inventory

Example 2:
Enter name and code of item1: bolt 11111

Enter name and code of item2: nut 22222

bolt goes before nut in the inventory

The current code that I have is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct partType {
    string name;
    int code;
};

int main() {

    partType nam, num;

    cout << "enter name and code of item1: ";
    cin >> nam.name >> num.code;
    cout << "enter name and code for item2: ";
    cin >> nam.name >> num.code;

    if (num.code > num.code) {
        cout << nam.name << " goes after " << nam.name;
    }
    else if (num.code < num.code) {
        cout << nam.name << " goes before " << nam.name;
    }
    else {
        cout << "tie";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I feel that I shouldn't be using the nam and num twice because it'll overwrite it but I'm not completely sure on how to fix it

Comment: I think you meant `cin >> nam.name >> nam.code;` followed by `cin >> num.name >> num.code` it would help if you used better variable names. Also your conditionals are comparing a value with itself, how would it ever be `<` or `>` compared to itself?

Comment: Tip: use a `vector<partType>`.

Comment: I know they're getting compared to themselves. That's the issue. We can only use two variables for the whole thing.

Comment: @clypefor No, you're literally comparing a variable to itself, which makes no sense whatsoever. For example, you do this: `if (num.code > num.code)`. I guarantee you `num.code` will never be greater than `num.code`. In fact, the guarantee is so solid the compiler is almost certainly just discarding that line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your code, you seem to be mixing up your `nam` and `num` variables.

```
partType nam, num;
```

This line creates two `partType` variables, one called `nam` and the other called `num`.

```
cout << "enter name and code of item1: ";
cin >> nam.name >> num.code;
```

Watch out! You prompt for the name and code for the first item, but you place the input for the code into the second variable!

```
cout << "enter name and code for item2: ";
cin >> nam.name >> num.code;
```

Instead of setting both fields of the second variable, `num`, you are only setting the `code` field of the second variable, but setting the `name` field of the first variable, and furthermore you are overwriting the data that was inputted from the first input prompt.

```
if (num.code > num.code) {
    cout << nam.name << " goes after " << nam.name;
}
else if (num.code < num.code) {
    cout << nam.name << " goes before " << nam.name;
}
```

You are comparing an expression to itself. You should do `num.code < nam.code` and vice versa instead.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. :)